# click event in google maps and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a map which have markers i try when a user click on a marker to make an AJAX request in php file , AJAX send as json the lat/long of marker and the lat/long of user in php file the file make a query in db and return an json array with geometries of result. when i run the mozila consol is hasnt show any error if i put an `alert(ar.latStart);` frond of ajax show the data.
The Json data

```
var coords = {'latStart': latPos , 'longStart' : longPos , 'latend' : latitude , 'longEnd' : longitude};
```

the event of google maps is

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var latitude = this.position.lat();
    var longitude = this.position.lng();            
    var coords = {'latStart': latPos , 'longStart' : longPos , 'latend' : latitude , 'longEnd' : longitude};            
    getCoords(coords);
});
```

the ajax function `getCoords` is

```
function getCoords(ar) {
        alert(ar.latStart); //the alert show the values is hasnt have problem

        $.ajax({
                url: 'routing.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: ar ,
                cache: false,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(rsp){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(rsp)); //show an empty alert
                }
        });
}
```

and the php file

```
if(isset($_GET['data'])){
    $obj = json_decode($_GET['data']);
    //some php operation
}
echo $obj;
```

The mozilla as i say is not show any problem in consol show an empty alert of the Ajax success.
Please if can any one help me i try it days but i cant find whats wrong

Comment: `echo json_encode($_GET['data']);`

Comment: It doesnt take in php file the array

Answer (score 0):

because there is no key in the request named `data` so this would not work:

```
 $_GET['data'] // because this key is not in the request.
```

instead you can try to send it like:

```
getCoords({"data":coords});
```

---

and at php end:

```
if(isset($_GET['data'])){
    $obj = json_decode($_GET['data']);
//some php operation
}
echo json_encode($obj); /*<---encode it and echo.*/
```

Comment: I make the change it not take the json array in php , i cant understand why make it